# the reality of reflection

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Today’s “Phrase of the Day” is “hold a mirror up to“ and it is a phrase meaning “to take a look at oneself objectively to examine or reflect on things (issues) stemming from **the reality of reflection**; to reveal to someone about the way they look (differently) to the rest of the world (so that they can reflect upon themselves); expose, show up, bring to light (some (unpleasant) aspects to oneself)”.
> Example Sentence: There’s an eight-year difference in life expectancy between the north and the south of the UK. These differences in life expectancy hold a mirror up to the inequalities across the nation.

[Source](https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/www.editorialwords.com/phrase-of-the-day-hold-a-mirror-up-to-20oct20/amp/)

---

What does "**the reality of reflection**" mean in the context given?

Comment: It's a terrible piece of writing, with an inapt metaphor. The example usage which looks at the differences in life expectancy isn't "holding a mirror up to" anything. *These differences in life expectancy expose the inequalities across the nation.*

Comment: To understand this particular metaphoric usage, you need to think of it from the perspective of a *single* person / entity which is both "the observer" and "the observed". Without such a metaphoric mirror, ***society*** would be unable to reflect upon (and hopefully deal with)  the inevitable injustices and other shortcoming that always arise when large numbers of people interact. Regardless of the overall quality of the cited extract, it's a perfectly natural idiomatic usage in context (*holds a mirror up to X = **exposes X, brings X into sharp focus,...***).

Comment: @WeatherVane  The author of the The Guardian article, where the sentence is cited from, is Doctor Horton and editor-in-chief of the Lancet. What's so terrible about the writing?

Comment: @Mari-Lou the example might be about "reflecting on differences" but "holding a mirror up" is about self-reflection.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - would you be happy with a Booker prize winner delivering your baby or performing surgery on you?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I asked Weather Vane why it is such “terrible piece of writing”. I didn't think so, and saw the author  is an experienced writer,  a competent native speaker and, presumably,  also a highly educated one. By the by Doctors, such as Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, have also written best selling novels.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Problems with that passage: (1) the first and third definitions both say it means "to take a look at **oneself**", but the object can be anyone, not just oneself; (2) the expression does not mean to "take a look", but to **cause** someone to take a look at themselves; (3) the phrase "the reality of reflection" is meaningless; (4) there should be a noun phrase, rather than a prepositional phrase after "reveal to someone"; (5) the second "definition" is a specific example of the first, except limited only to others; ... (1/2)

Comment: ... (6) the example sentence is an incorrect usage because the object of the final "to" must be a person or group of people, not the issue itself. (2/2)

Comment: @gotube I was referring *only* to the example sentence (6), which is from The Guardian  article, written by Dr. Horton. I thought I made it pretty clear. Is that a  piece of "terrible writing"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah, then only my comment (6) is relevant to your comment, but all apply to Weather Vane's assessment of it overall being "*a terrible piece of writing*."

Comment: @gotube Weather Vane's comment was directed at the example sentence. When I asked, they focused on the sentence not on the English website, Editorial Words, and their “Phrase of the Day”.  On the other hand,  the metaphorical **holding a mirror up to the inequalities of the nation** I find reasonable, so does Fumble Fingers, even if the object is not a person or a group but an abstract noun. Perhaps posting on EL&U about this specific sentence will lead to other users agreeing with Weather's and you for the same reasons. Then again, the question risks being closed as being opinion based.